# .htaccess file configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please Help me to solve this problem. I have a php project with .htaccess file which contains code like this -

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^files/([0-9]+)/(.*)([/]?)$ download.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

So, I have to servers, on the first server my project works correctly, but on the second server I can see only home page, I mean when I am trying to go another page, for instance About me, this error appears`

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /my_site/eng/aboutme/ was not found on this server.

I think it is connected with .htaccess file.

Please help me.

Comment: You should check that in which folder your site is run. I think this is not the problem of this file else the problem is in your folder where it is place.

Comment: But what problem it could be, you mean ? Do u have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^files/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$ download.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

- You were missing L flag in all the rules.
- You need to relax last rule to capture everything to be handled by index.php eventually.
- Also important is to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to prevent looping.

Comment: Thank you but I copied and pasted, but no result :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `no result` :) What is the URI that you tried and? What error did you get?

Comment: This is the error. And it does not depend on what URI I want to open, because it works only in case of home page.
The requested URL /mysite/eng/aboutme/ was not found on this server

Comment: Ok can you see if this URI works '/index.php?page=/mysite/eng/aboutme/` ?

Comment: Also can you also post your latest .htaccess here in your question (not in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the other server has mod_rewrite installed? If url rewriting doesn't work it a missing rewrite engine 90% of the time.